# php strlen function can not work perfectly

Tags: php

The `strlen` function works fine when I echo a **given variable** but when I give input **using stdin** then `strlen` doesn't work as expected.

```
<?php   
function CheckUsername($username){
  $static ="This is a pen";
  echo strlen($static);

  **Output:13**
  **usng stdin (same input:This is a pen)**

  echo (strlen($username));

  **output:4**
}

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin','r');
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout','w');
$testCase = 0; 
$username = 0;

fscanf(STDIN,"%d\n",$testCase); 
for($i=0;$i<$testCase;$i++) {
  fscanf(STDIN,"%s\n",$username); 
  $result = CheckUsername($username); 

  fprintf(STDOUT,"%s\n",$result); 
}
```

Why is the result not 13?

Comment: Please show a code example.

Comment: Echo the contents of the output from (stdin) before counting its string length.

Comment: @Niek van der Maaden : can you give me a sample example

Comment: var_dump($username) that you get from your stdin/out function, so we can see what content it holds.

Comment: string(4) "This" . .it shows when i var_dump($username)

Comment: Thats the reason why strlen returns 4. $username from your stdin/out function only returns "this" != "this is a pen"

Comment: FYI, that's actually a very good question. I reckon you got those downvotes because it's very poorly formatted and hard to understand what you mean with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `STDIN`, but with how `fscanf()` works, which in short is just `sscanf()` reading from a file pointer.

And ... as you can see below, it treats whitespace as the *separator* between `%s` tokens:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > var_dump(sscanf("This is a pen", "%s\n"));
php shell code:1:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "This"
}
```

If you insist on using `fscanf()` for this, a little-known feature is that it also accepts regex-like character classes, so you could for example tell it to look for anything that's not a newline character:

```
php > var_dump(sscanf("This is a pen", "%[^\n]"));
php shell code:1:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(13) "This is a pen"
}
```

However, at that point I have to question why would you use `fscanf()` instead of `fgets()`, which does exactly that - read an entire line, stopping at `\n`.

Comment: Valid point, comments above where more to show that he has to debug his variables more than just comparing with strlen, as pointed above the content of each string is completely different.

Comment: I always use fscanf thats why i use it. and work perfectly  but this time its not working

Comment: @shahidcse29 It work's for `%s %s` with an input of `foo bar`, but `%s%s` will also work in that case - the space you put in the format string is ignored.